# Angular JS is not displaying clock

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am absolutely new to angular JS and going through the tutorial of ng-book. I am trying to add a clock on the page but the page is showing `Hello {{clock}}` instead of actual clock. I am using **`Angular 1.4.8`**.

Here is my code.

clock.html

```
 <!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <title>Angular clock demo</title>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"  ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyController">
            <h1>Hello {{ clock }}</h1>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

code for js/app.js

```
function MyController($scope) {
    $scope.clock = new Date();

    var updateClock = function(){
        $scope.clock = new Date();
    };

    setInterval(function(){
        $scope.$apply(updateClock);
    },1000);

    updateClock();
};
```

Comment: do you have any script errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From angular 1.3.x global controller isn't allowed by default.

Bind your controller with module

Like this

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("MyController",MyController);
```

html

```
ng-app="app"
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/c1d0dtcs/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you Anik. You saved me apparently I am reading old book but using new library.